# The following packages will be SUPERCEDED by a higher-priority channel

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I get this message all the time when I try to update packages and I usually just proceed and everything generally works out. But I'm concerned that I've accidentally created a much more complex Anaconda environment than I meant to. This thread ([What does "the following packages will be superseded by a higher priority channel" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41461582/what-does-the-following-packages-will-be-superseded-by-a-higher-priority-channe)) mentions giving other channels higher priority. If that's what I've done, how can I undo it?

Here's an example of the message:

```
conda install -c anaconda flask=0.12
Fetching package metadata .............
Solving package specifications: .

Package plan for installation in environment C:\Users\HMGSYS\Anaconda3:

The following packages will be SUPERCEDED by a higher-priority channel:

    conda:     4.3.8-py35_0  --> 4.2.13-py35_0 anaconda
    conda-env: 2.6.0-0       --> 2.6.0-0       anaconda

Proceed ([y]/n)?
```

However, if I don't specify the version number, it appears to want to downgrade my flask version:

```
 conda install -c anaconda flask
Fetching package metadata .............
Solving package specifications: .

Package plan for installation in environment C:\Users\HMGSYS\Anaconda3:

The following packages will be UPDATED:

    anaconda:  4.3.0-np111py35_0 --> custom-py35_0 anaconda

The following packages will be SUPERCEDED by a higher-priority channel:

    conda:     4.3.8-py35_0      --> 4.2.13-py35_0 anaconda
    conda-env: 2.6.0-0           --> 2.6.0-0       anaconda
    flask:     0.12-py35_0       --> 0.11.1-py35_0 anaconda

Proceed ([y]/n)?
```

But my main question isn't about flask versions, it's asking what I did to end up with multiple channels, and how do I simply it down to one. I've seen several comments that suggest modifying the .condarc file, but I don't have one (which is the default) so I don't think that's creating the problem.

In case this helps, my output from conda info is:

Current conda install:

```
           platform : win-64
      conda version : 4.3.8
   conda is private : False
  conda-env version : 4.3.8
conda-build version : 2.1.3
     python version : 3.5.2.final.0
   requests version : 2.12.4
   root environment : C:\Users\HMGSYS\Anaconda3  (writable)
default environment : C:\Users\HMGSYS\Anaconda3
   envs directories : C:\Users\HMGSYS\Anaconda3\envs
      package cache : C:\Users\HMGSYS\Anaconda3\pkgs
       channel URLs : https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/win-64
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/noarch
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/win-64
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/msys2/noarch
        config file : None
       offline mode : False
         user-agent : conda/4.3.8 requests/2.12.4 CPython/3.5.2 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.14393
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The command you're writing is

```
conda install -c anaconda flask
```

`conda install` tells Conda to install a package (obviously), and `flask` is the name of the package. Although you may not have any channels listed in your `.condarc` file, you are telling conda to use a specific channel **and give it the highest priority** with the `-c anaconda` part of that command. So `conda install` goes out to the web and finds the best package matches that it can, taking into account that you're telling it that it should prefer packages from the `anaconda` channel. However, the `anaconda` channel doesn't have `flask=0.12` on it, the highest version they have (for your platform) is `flask=0.11.1`. You can see here for a list of all the versions that they have available on that channel: https://anaconda.org/anaconda/flask/files

So here's what's happening

```
conda install -c anaconda flask=0.12
```

goes to look for all the packages it can find from the `anaconda` channel. It can't find `flask=0.12` for your platform, so since you have it installed, it does nothing. However, it does find versions of `conda` and `conda-env` on that channel, so it decides to download them from the `anaconda` channel, because you gave it the highest priority, even though the version is lower.

```
conda install -c anaconda flask
```

also goes to look for all the packages it can find from the `anaconda` channel. Since you didn't specify a version for `flask`, `conda` looks for the most recent version it can find on the channel that you specified. Since you already have `flask` installed from a different channel (in this case, the `defaults` channel), installing the version from the `anaconda` channel will supercede the version you have.

Comment: So is it a good idea to let conda do that? I mean supercede a lower version against a higher available one, especially if that one is downloaded from a trusted repository? Will the packages break if I specify no?

Comment: That depends on the package and its dependencies. I would say that you should install any custom packages into a separate environment, rather than the environment with `anaconda` installed.